# db.session.commit() does not save the change in the database

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

this is my code

```
    @app.route('/certification', methods=['POST'])
    def certificationVector():
        # get data from database; it works correctly
        if request.is_json:
            data = request.get_json()
            print(data)
            description = data['description']
            print("descrrrr", description)
            id_certification = data['id_certification']
    
            vector = textToVect(description)
            print("vect ", vector)
            vector_str = ','.join(map(str, vector))
            # id_offer = data['id_offer'],

            # update the column certification_vector in table certification
            certification_to_update = db.session.query(Certification).filter_by(id=id_certification).first()
            print("ppp", certification_to_update.id)
            certification_to_update.certification_vector = ''.join(map(str, vector))
            print("dbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb", certification_to_update.certification_vector)
            db.session.commit()
            
            print("zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz")
            response = jsonify(id_certification=certification_to_update.id)
    
            return response
    
        else:
            return {"error": "The request payload is not in JSON format"}
```

Comment: Can you fix your formatting? Also, which database are you using?

Comment: Missing `db.session.add(certificate_to_update`

Comment: @Dave You don't need a `db.session.add` if you're just doing an update